# Meteor programmable templates or wildcard templates

Tags: templates, meteor, handlebars.js

I want to use the same code for multiple instances of a chatroom on screen.

Let's say I want to have 6 chatrooms onscreen at the same time, but each of them using the same template uh, template, but difference instances, but still being able to react independently in the Meteor way.

How do I do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `collection` of chatrooms, and use the `each` helper to iterate over each of the current chatrooms. Inside of that iterator, you'd have another template for `chatroom`. You'd then, in effect, be using the same template for multiple chatrooms. This is a very common design pattern for Meteor.

```
<template name='chatrooms'>
  {{#each chatrooms}}
    {{>chatroom}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name='chatroom'>
  <div class='room'>
  {{name}}
  <ul>
   {{#each messages}}
    <li>{{text}}</li>
   {{/each}}
  </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: But what if I don't want to put the chatrooms inside the same container, but in different places? For example I have a chatroom inside a popup, or I can have it inside a sidebar, or embeded into the main content depending on various settings?

Comment: You can reuse templates by calling them in different contexts. So within your popup, you could still embed the template using `{{>chatroom}}`. In the popup template you could then use `{{#with}}` to specify what chatroom you're dealing with. I think that'd work...